# Htaccess/Htpasswd AutoType Basic Doesn't Work in Chrome

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, .htpasswd

Okay, so I'm protecting a webpage with a basic `.htaccess`/`.htpasswd` combination.

My `.htaccess` file looks something like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
AuthUserFile HOMEDIRECTORY/.htpasswd  
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic  
require valid-user
```

Everything works fine under Firefox, but Chrome gives this message. I've tested this on multiple computers.

> Authorization Required
>
> This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Any idea where Chrome is going wrong?

Comment: The error message is coming from the server, not Chrome.

Comment: The whole login prompt works perfectly smoothly in Firefox.

Comment: I believe you but that error is a server error.

Comment: But I'm not sure what we can do for you without seeing the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a *frame redirection* between different domains Chrome will not show the login prompt. Use an HTTP 302 or 301 redirection instead.